# How do I prevent Visual Basic 2008 from automatically indenting namespaces?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

```
Namespace testing
    Public Module TestModule
        Public testobj As New test
    End Module
End Namespace
```

It is extremely annoying to have to start out two tabs to the right on new code. Is there anyway to disable auto-indenting just for namespace declarations in visual studio 2008?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no setting for turning off specific block type indentations.  (There is a setting for C# to turn off block indenting altogether, but again, not specific to certain block types like namespace blocks).

You shouldn't need to hit tab twice though - when you press "enter" on a line of code, it should automatically indent you to where the last line was indented to.

And no matter how you type in your code, it's just a quick keystroke to auto-format the whole document (Ctrl-K followed by Ctrl-D).  So you can ignore idents until you're done typing and then auto-format.